# How to test HTML parser written in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, nokogiri

I have a parser for HTML documents with Nokogiri in Ruby, and I am asking you what testing framework would be ideal to maintain the parser?

The testing framework should support writing tests in Ruby.

**What I want to test:**

- Consistency of data (HTML can change and I have to be sure that data is still available/parseable)

Any ideas?

I am not sure what kind of information would be useful to improve my answer, so please leave a comment in case there are uncertainties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test/unit in the stdlib is more than sufficient.

require "test/unit"